# load posts by click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to load posts by click, I have two files

- index.php with ajax
- handler.php.

I'm studying AJAX. I understand this technology so by clicking on the button an Ajax request should occur, then the handler returns the data to the Ajax request, and the Ajax query outputs this data. But I can not do it, why? How to fix the error? My error is that the posts are not loaded. The console is empty. I set the echo to the top of the handler, but it did not work. I guess the problem with ajax

**index.php with ajax**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <!-- <article class="news">
                <div class="picture"><img src="1news.jpg" width="300" height="300"></div>
                <div class="aboutpost">
                    <h2 class="aboutpost-title">Пожар в торговом центре в Кемерово</h2>
                    <p class="aboutpost-description">Холдинг, куда входило ЧОП "Зимней вишни", прекратил работу после трагедии</p>
                </div>
            </article> -->
            <?php
                require 'infofordb.php';
                $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
                $query ="SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5";
                $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
                $articles = array();
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {$articles[] = $row;}
                foreach($articles as $article) {echo '
            <article class="news">
                <div class="picture">
                    <img src="/image/'.$article[path].'">
                </div>
                <div class="aboutpost">
                    <h2 class="aboutpost-title">'.$article[title].'</h2>
                    <p class="aboutpost-description">'.$article[description].'</p>
                </div>
            </article>';}
            ?>
            <center><button id="load">Загрузить ещё</button></center>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    var inProgress = false;
                    var start = 5;
                    $('#load').click(function() {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'handler.php',
                            method: 'POST',
                            data: {"start" : start},
                            dataType: 'json',
                            beforeSend: function() {inProgress = true;}
                        }).done(function(data){
                            data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                            alert('nen');
                            if (data.length > 0) {
                                //надо вывести
                                $.each(data, function(index, data){
                                    $('main').append(
                                        '<article class="news"><div class="picture"><img src="/image/' + data.path +
                                        + '"></div><div class="aboutpost"><h2 class="aboutpost-title">' + data.title + 
                                        + '</h2><p class="aboutpost-description">' + data.description + 
                                        + '</p></div></article>');
                                });
                                inProgress = false;
                                start += 5;
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

**handler.php**

```
<?php
    include(infofordb.php);
    $start = $_POST['start'];
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
    $query ="SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT {$start}, 5";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
    $articles = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {$articles[] = $row;}
    echo json_encode($articles);
?>
```

Comment: **How to fix the error?** And what is your error?

Comment: What is the error? Did you check the console?

Comment: do you get the alert('nen')? have you tried putin ( :)) ) some simple output in handler.php?

Comment: what version of jquery you're using?, don't forget to open your browser console to check for significant errors

Comment: maybe your jquery file not getting correct path.

Comment: @Musa My mistake is that the posts are not loaded. The console is empty

Comment: You are supposed to mention the error here.

Comment: @Ghost jquery-3.3.1.min.js

Comment: @Anandagrawal The path is correct

Comment: @damirqasha `$query ="SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT {$start}, 5";`, i think this should be `$query ="SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$start.", 5";`

Comment: @Bernhard Sorry, I did not understand you. If you are talking about the echo in the handler.php, then the echo does not work

Comment: @SachiTekina Does not work

Comment: I set the echo to the top of the handler, but it did not work. I guess the problem with ajax

Comment: Then what does the error say? Try `print_r(json_encode($articles))`, the query string is incorrect.

Comment: @SachiTekina Yes, I realized that the query string is incorrect, I corrected it. What you did not advise did not work. It seems to me the handler does not start

Answer (score 0):

`dataType: 'json',` tells jQuery to parse the returned JSON data. In your code, you call JSON.parse which attempts to parse it again, remove that line(this line I mean `data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);`).

Comment: Everything also does not load posts

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your mysql Query in handler.php

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT {$start}, 5";
```

The curly braces does not work in query. May be this solve your problem.